# Meaning of '^=' bitwise operator

Tags: bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

Can somebody explain to me what is the meaning of '^=' operator in Java? I know that '^' is a bitwise operator, but '^=' it's a bit confusing.
I searched on the Google, but still is unclear.

Comment: which programming language?

Comment: Have a look at compound operators: https://www.baeldung.com/java-compound-operators. `a ^= b` is equivalent to `a = a ^ b`

Answer (score 0):

^= applies the bitwise operator and sets a variable equal to the result of the operation.

```
var_a ^= var_b
```

is equivalent to

```
var_a = var_a ^ var_b
```

Like +=, -=, or other shorthands like those.